# Share folders/files between two users (websites) on same server

Tags: php, apache, debian, webmin, php-include

I have dedicated server and a few websites on it, but I need to allow PHP to use/include files between two sites.

For example, the first website has file on this location `/home/first/public_html/lib/mainclass.php`

I need to include that file on the second website (`/home/second/`) in some file like this:

```
<?php
include('/home/first/public_html/lib/mainclass.php');
```

What exactly I need to do for that? Server is on Debian, and I have Virtulamin/Webmin—so it will be good if I can do that within.
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about library files that you share now between 2 but in the future between perhaps more sites, I would put them  in the php default `include_path` (for example `/php/includes`) or a sub-directory of that.

Or add a new directory outside of the individual user's home directories to store the library files and add that to the php `include_path`.

That way they are always accessible to all sites on that server and they can only be modified by someone who has access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

This requires, in general, read permission (of the second php file, by the webserver). There may be an option somewhere in php to deny access to some folder, but if the second website shows up as normal, then there shouldn't be a problem.